# C# - Azure AD - Issue with redirect after login

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory

I'm using Azure AD Connection for integrated login in an ASP.Net website.

If I use the same code and same configurations in a brand new project, it works. When implementing in my main project, it has some unusual behaviour.

Startup.cs is the following:

```
public class startup
{
    string clientId = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];
    string redirectUri = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectUri"];
    static string tenant = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tenant"];
    string authority = String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Authority"], tenant);

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = clientId,
            Authority = authority,
            RedirectUri = redirectUri,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
            Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
            ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidateIssuer = false
            },
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
            }
        }
    );
    }

    private Task OnAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> context)
    {
        context.HandleResponse();
        context.Response.Redirect("/?errormessage=" + context.Exception.Message);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

My c# code in login page:

```
 protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SignIn();
}

public void SignIn()
{
    if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
            new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/MainAzure.aspx" },
            OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    }
    else
        Response.Redirect("MainAzure.aspx");
}
```

The issue is this:
When I Press the login button in my aspx page, it opens the Microsoft login page. When I select the account and enter the password, it redirects to my redirect page (MainAzure.aspx) but without the authentication properties. Request.IsAuthenticated returns false.

Any hints?

Comment: Pls refer to this code sample published by MS - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi.git
Request.IsAuthenticated is not used in Sign In.

Comment: Did the below response work for you?

Comment: I'll answer as soon as possible, still haven't tried! thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your implementation as below approach:

**Startup.cs :**

```
public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }

        /*
        * Configure the OWIN middleware
        */

        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Required for Azure webapps, as by default they force TLS 1.2 and this project attempts 1.0
            ..ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    // Generate the metadata address using the tenant and policy information
                    MetadataAddress = String.Format(Globals.WellKnownMetadata, Globals.Tenant, Globals.DefaultPolicy),

                    // These are standard OpenID Connect parameters, with values pulled from web.config
                    ClientId = Globals.ClientId,
                    RedirectUri = Globals.RedirectUri,
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = Globals.RedirectUri,

                    // Specify the callbacks for each type of notifications
                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                    {
                        RedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider,
                        AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
                        AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
                    },

                    // Specify the claim type that specifies the Name property.
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        NameClaimType = "name",
                        ValidateIssuer = false
                    },

                    // Specify the scope by appending all of the scopes requested into one string (separated by a blank space)
                    Scope = $"openid profile offline_access {Globals.ReadTasksScope} {Globals.WriteTasksScope}"
                }
            );
        }

        /*
         *  On each call to Azure AD B2C, check if a policy (e.g. the profile edit or password reset policy) has been specified in the OWIN context.
         *  If so, use that policy when making the call. Also, don't request a code (since it won't be needed).
         */
        private Task OnRedirectToIdentityProvider(RedirectToIdentityProviderNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
        {
            var policy = notification.OwinContext.Get<string>("Policy");

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(policy) && !policy.Equals(Globals.DefaultPolicy))
            {
                notification.ProtocolMessage.Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenId;
                notification.ProtocolMessage.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken;
                notification.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = notification.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress.ToLower().Replace(Globals.DefaultPolicy.ToLower(), policy.ToLower());
            }

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        /*
         * Catch any failures received by the authentication middleware and handle appropriately
         */
        private Task OnAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
        {
            notification.HandleResponse();

            // Handle the error code that Azure AD B2C throws when trying to reset a password from the login page
            // because password reset is not supported by a "sign-up or sign-in policy"
            if (notification.ProtocolMessage.ErrorDescription != null && notification.ProtocolMessage.ErrorDescription.Contains("AADB2C90118"))
            {
                // If the user clicked the reset password link, redirect to the reset password route
                notification.Response.Redirect("/Account/ResetPassword");
            }
            else if (notification.Exception.Message == "access_denied")
            {
                notification.Response.Redirect("/");
            }
            else
            {
                notification.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error?message=" + notification.Exception.Message);
            }

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        /*
         * Callback function when an authorization code is received
         */
        private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification notification)
        {
            try
            {
                /*
                 The `MSALPerUserMemoryTokenCache` is created and hooked in the `UserTokenCache` used by `IConfidentialClientApplication`.
                 At this point, if you inspect `ClaimsPrinciple.Current` you will notice that the Identity is still unauthenticated and it has no claims,
                 but `MSALPerUserMemoryTokenCache` needs the claims to work properly. Because of this sync problem, we are using the constructor that
                 receives `ClaimsPrincipal` as argument and we are getting the claims from the object `AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification context`.
                 This object contains the property `AuthenticationTicket.Identity`, which is a `ClaimsIdentity`, created from the token received from
                 Azure AD and has a full set of claims.
                 */
                IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClient = MsalAppBuilder.BuildConfidentialClientApplication(new ClaimsPrincipal(notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity));

                // Upon successful sign in, get & cache a token using MSAL
                AuthenticationResult result = await confidentialClient.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(Globals.Scopes, notification.Code).ExecuteAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage
                {
                    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                    ReasonPhrase = $"Unable to get authorization code {ex.Message}."
                });
            }
        }
```

**(For user authentication activities) AccountController.cs :**

```
public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        /*
         *  Called when requesting to sign up or sign in
         */
        public void SignUpSignIn(string redirectUrl)
        {
            redirectUrl = redirectUrl ?? "/";

            // Use the default policy to process the sign up / sign in flow
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUrl });
            return;
        }

        /*
         *  Called when requesting to edit a profile
         */
        public void EditProfile()
        {
            if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                // Let the middleware know you are trying to use the edit profile policy (see OnRedirectToIdentityProvider in Startup.Auth.cs)
                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Set("Policy", Globals.EditProfilePolicyId);

                // Set the page to redirect to after editing the profile
                var authenticationProperties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" };
                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(authenticationProperties);

                return;
            }

            Response.Redirect("/");
        }

        /*
         *  Called when requesting to reset a password
         */
        public void ResetPassword()
        {
            // Let the middleware know you are trying to use the reset password policy (see OnRedirectToIdentityProvider in Startup.Auth.cs)
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Set("Policy", Globals.ResetPasswordPolicyId);

            // Set the page to redirect to after changing passwords
            var authenticationProperties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" };
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(authenticationProperties);

            return;
        }

        /*
         *  Called when requesting to sign out
         */
        public async Task SignOut()
        {
            // To sign out the user, you should issue an OpenIDConnect sign out request.
            if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                await MsalAppBuilder.ClearUserTokenCache();
                IEnumerable<AuthenticationDescription> authTypes = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetAuthenticationTypes();
                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(authTypes.Select(t => t.AuthenticationType).ToArray());
                Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetAuthenticationTypes();
            }
        }
    }
```

For complete code, you can visit [Azure AD B2C: Call an ASP.NET Web API from an ASP.NET Web App](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi)